# Why don't the owners of a chatroom receive notifications?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

Today I realized that an owner of a chatroom does not receive **any** notification if somebody else leave a comment in your chatroom (unless they ping you).

This does not makes much sense to me.

On the information of the chatroom says that you are the owner, that is, if someone goes there to ask something, you should be *aware about it* so that you could be there to help them (or at least try), by receiving a notification, to receive a notification saying that someone left a comment and so you might go there later.

I think the owner has a responsibility for the actions that happen in that chatroom.

Can we have this new feature please?

Thank you.

**edit**

By reading curious's comment, I can see that this could be very problematic if receiving hundreds of comments a day. So this feature would be more appropriated if can be *enable* and *disable* whenever one decides to.

**edit 2**

What I mean with notification is to receive a notification like the ones you get when someone leaves a comment on one of your questions/answer or when they ping you, and so at some point you get a notification on your mail. So even if you are not on SE sites, you'll know what's going on. Sorry for not to specify.

Comment: I believe that owners of rooms that have lots of activity in them may disagree with this, just saying.

Comment: I can definitely see the use for this in small rooms but we should be able to disable it (for reasons mentioned above).

Comment: @curious Thanks for pointing out that. I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

The Feature ("receive a notification saying that someone left a comment") is [configurable](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications):

> "There is a configurable sound trigger in every room, at the top of the page.
>
> [image: Sound Notifications]
>
> Sounds can be set to occur only when you are mentioned, for new messages on visible rooms, for new messages on any room you're in … or not at all. ...".

It is possible for anyone to get a ping on any comment in any room they are in, producing a [cacophony](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cacophony) of dings. The default is "when mentioned" (using an @).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that kind of notifications. Perhaps I should have been more specific in my question. I meant to receive a notification assuming that you are not on a SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is necessary, and I suspect that most room owners wouldn't want it. Consider that active rooms on the network can receive a hundred new messages a day; during very active surges, even a hundred messages in an hour. If room owners received notifications every time a new message was posted they would be getting notifications all day. This would quickly become an annoyance to them.

Room owners also tend to be active participants in the room. They probably visit the room on a daily basis, if they aren't simply camped out there at all times. It is therefore likely that room owners would have seen the new messages without any notifications. And even if they haven't seen new messages from the past few hours it is trivially easy for them to quickly scroll through the room's transcript to see what they missed.

Comment: Just some comments, not all room owners tend to be active participants in the room whence not even daily. And _no_ it's not likely that room owners would have seen the new messages without any notifications.

Comment: I once left a comment on a math chatroom and it took them 15 hours to reply to my request, and it turns out the one who replied to my request was not even an owner of such chatroom. I have always thought that the owners got a notification whenever someone left a comment.

Comment: @Bellatrix What kind of requests are you making in a chat room?

Comment: I asked to cancel my bounty on one of my _Measure Theory_ questions. This was in june I think

Comment: @Bellatrix Chat is not the correct place to make such requests. Room owners don't have any special privileges on the site itself, and things which require moderator action should be flagged with "in need of moderator intervention" flag.

Comment: It was [math mods office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) that chatroom it's supposed to comunicate with mods

Comment: @Bellatrix I can't speak to whether individual rooms have unique protocols, but in any case you can ping people in a chat room (if they've been in the room recently) if you are trying to talk directly to them, and that will give them a notification.

Comment: Yes, I know. That works fine. But, for people who don't know, they are likely to be ignored, and of course with no malicity. See I recently created my [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103446/bounty-chatroom-) and I got no notification of Martin's comment.

Comment: @Bellatrix Without speaking to your specific situation (since I don't know the details), it seems unlikely that a message in a chat room would get no response at all. Unless the room has little to no activity there will usually be someone to advise the person, even if it's not the one who was being sought.

Comment: @Bellatrix You've mentioned your request from Math Mods' Office as an example. I suppose you refer to [these messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2019/6/21). I will add also link to the [response in that room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2019/6/22), where the advice was to flag or to ping one of the mods.

Comment: @Martin now I know, but I think that if mods would have been notified right after I had posted my comment, I would have not lost my +50 points; that it's because currently when I go to Math Mods' Office and then ping quid, quid responds promptly :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is implemented, please disable it by default. I'm one of the room owners of the [main room of Code Review](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and I don't need hundreds of notifications each day. I practically live there anyway, so I don't *need* the notifications to know what's going on.

For smaller rooms, rooms that are only active once every so many days, I could see a benefit. But it better be optional or you'll see a lot of room owners leaving their post.

As for your following statement:

> I think the owner has a responsibility for the actions that happen in that chatroom.

Yes and no. As a room owner you're somewhat more responsible for what happens there than the average user. But in the end, the room owner only has limited capabilities and is more of a look-out than a guard. If things repeatedly escalate in a room while there are experienced room owners present, they're not doing their job. But that doesn't mean they're the ones responsible nothing untoward happens.

The moment you start a room you're the owner of that room. If a troll decides to come into that room after I haven't been there for days and I happen to be on holiday, is it my responsibility what happens in that room? It better not be. We'll help where I can, but it's not realistic to have all rooms sewn up by room owners.

Having a couple of active room owners in big rooms really helps. But who is responsible according to you if there's 7 room owners, of which 2 moderators, of which 4 are currently 'in the room' and something happens? Should 7 people get pinged and feel responsible for that ping just to get a Fastest Gun In The West scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lets take your example about the 'troll'. Say a troll went to your chatroom to mess up while you are on holiday vacations. As you are on vacations, you simply turn off your phone. At some point, say you have "spare time" and decide to turn on your phone and so all your mail,msg,SE notifications start to pop up _but_ as there's **no** chatroom notifications then you simply don't check SE chatrooms. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, that's what my **edit 1** concerns about. One should have the option to enable or disable at any time.

Comment: When I said I basically lived there, I wasn't kidding. I *will* check that room at my earliest convenience and *will* find another RO or mod has already taken care of it. SE even has a join favourite rooms option, joining a starred rooms with one click.